# Use a bash script if it exists on the path, otherwise use an executable

Tags: macos, bash, xcode

I want to use a bash script if it exists on the path, and otherwise, I would like to use an executable.

```
alias build='xctool.sh'
type -a xctool.sh || alias build='xcodebuild'
build -scheme "${APP_SCHEME}" archive
```

So in this example I want to use xctool.sh instead of xcodebuild if it's available.
Otherwise I want xcodebuild to be used.

The error I get is "build: command not found"

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe works perfectly if run on the command line, if you're having problems, I assume you are trying to do this as part of a script (hint: this is the kind of thing you want to mention in your question).

Scripts are run in a non-interactive shell and in this kind of shell aliases are not expanded. From `man bash`:

```
   Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless  the
   expand_aliases  shell option is set using `shopt`
```

So, you have a few choices. First, you can activate aliases in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias build='xctool.sh'
type -a xctool.sh 2>/dev/null || alias build='xcodebuild'
build -scheme "${APP_SCHEME}" archive
```

Alternatively, you can avoid aliases altogether by using `eval`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

build='xctool.sh'
type -a xctool.sh 2>/dev/null || build='xcodebuild'
$build -scheme ${APP_SCHEME} archive
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your last suggestion first thing monday morning. Sounds like a winner.

Comment: Wouldn't the last line work equally well without `eval`? (and be less prone to expansion problems): `$build -scheme "${APP_SCHEME}" archive`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, what `type` should do here; but when I get you right, something like this may be helpful:

```
[ -x ./xctool.sh ] && alias build='./xctool.sh' || alias build='xcodebuild'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `man test` -e / -f flags.

Maybe some thing like this works:

```
[ -f xctool.sh ] && xctool.sh || xcodebuild
```